# Почему в объекте переменные родителя

Tags: java

Был на тестировании по Java и столкнулся со следующей задачей.

```
package com.test;

import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
        B b = new B();
        System.out.println(a.x);
        System.out.println(b.x);
    }
}

class A {
    int x = 1;
    A() {
        this.x = 2;
        System.out.println("Зашли в конструктор A");
        System.out.println(this.x);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    int x = 3;
    B() {
        this.x = 4;
        System.out.println("Зашли в конструктор B");
        System.out.println(this.x);
    }
}
```

В консоли, внезапно, следующее:

```
Зашли в конструктор A
2
Зашли в конструктор B
4
Зашли в конструктор A
2
Зашли в конструктор B
4
2
4
```

Переменные, насколько я понимаю относятся к объекту, а не к ссылке. более того, я еще мог бы сам себе это объяснить, если бы не задал бы явно в конструкторе this.x=, мол возможно действительно переменная обносится к ссылке и храниться вообще в стеке а не в куче, но тут явно используется конструктор от класса B....

Соответственно вопрос: почему?

Comment: Конструктор В вызывает конструктор базового класса инициализируя обе переменные. А в main вы работаете со ссылками на разные типы, и следовательно получаете разные значения Х

Comment: т.е. при A a = new B(); создается несколько объектов? Т.е. объект класса А с x = 2 и объект класса B с переменной x=4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это явление называется `shadowing`.

`x` в `A` и `x` в `B` - это разные переменные. Когда Вы обращаетесь к `a.x`, это `x` из `A`, так как тип `a` - `A`. Что бы получить доступ к `B.x` из ссылки `a`, надо сделать `((B)a).x`.

Если Вы хотите, чтобы это была одна и та же переменная, закомментируйте `int x;` в классе `B`.

Для интереса, добавьте в конструктор `B`:

```
System.out.println(((A)this).x);
```

Answer (score 3):

В отличие от методов переменные не переопределяются в подклассах, они затеняются. Есть такое понятие, как `shadowing`.

Когда вы создаете объект типа `B`, он содержит в себе как поле `B.x`, принадлежащее `B`, так и `A.x`, принадлежащее `A`. Только в `A` оно затенилось и его не видно из `B`, так как `B` имеет переменную с таким же именем. Единственный способ его увидеть, это обратиться к объекту с типом родительского объекта `A`, что вы и делаете:
`System.out.println(a.x);`
Потому что объект `а` был создан с типом `A`:
`A a = new B();`